# UIView angle in circular motion

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a requirement where I will move my finger in the circular motion on the iphone touch screen and i need the current angle parallely. I will apply this angle to my uiview and will rotate it. PLease, can anybody help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the touchesBegan:withEvent: and touchesMoved:withEvent: methods. In began, record the position of the point where the touch began, and in each touchesMoved call, calculate the angle wrt the original point, and rotate the view accordingly.